# How to pass information from a member variable to a member method while using node-cron?

Tags: node.js, node-cron

If I have something like this:

```
Foo = function  (bar_) {
    this.bar = bar_;
    this.run = function() {
    cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', function() {
       console.log(/*this.bar?*/);
    });
}

var myvar = new Foo("mybar");
myvar.run();
```

How can I set the cron to print out this.bar's value at the time this.run is called? I've tried with this.bar and it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Foo = function  (bar_) {
this.bar = bar_;
var that = this
this.run = function() {
   cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', function() {
      console.log(that.bar);
   });
}

var myvar = new Foo("mybar");
myvar.run();
```

The explanation comes as follow:
**this** is a reference to the instance of class **Foo**, but it's also the default reference for any instantiated object to itself.

So, inside of cron.schedule call, **this** points to **cron** and not to **Foo**. Copying **this** to **that** before , and using **that** inside cron.shcedule gives you the correct object ("this") you're looking for

Comment: would there be any difference if I put the line you added into the run function?

Comment: probably not, but, not sure